# Java - Converting hours(in double) to minutes(integer) and vice versa

Tags: java, datetime, decimal, fractions

I need the correct formula that will convert hours to minutes and vice versa.
I have written a code, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. 
For eg:
If I have hours=8.16, then minutes should be 490, but I'm getting the result as 489.

```
  import java.io.*;
  class DoubleToInt {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

  BufferedReader buff = 
  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
  System.out.println("Enter the double hours:");
  String d = buff.readLine();

  double hours = Double.parseDouble(d);
  int min = (int) ((double)hours * 60);

  System.out.println("Minutes:=" + min);
  }
}
```

Comment: Double / Float arithmetics are not exact. You will probably have to use a BigDecimal with a custom MathContext.

Comment: Depending on certain assumptions the ceil function would work for you.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)

Comment: I will be using Bohemian's idea..thankyou for your suggestion anyway..I will keep that in mind:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because casting to `int` *truncates* the fractional part - it doesn't round it:

```
8.16 * 60 = 489.6
```

When cast to `int`, it becomes 489.

Consider using [`Math.round()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) for your calculations:

```
int min = (int) Math.round(hours * 60);
```

Note: `double` has limited accuracy and suffers from "small remainder error" issues, but using [`Math.round()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) will solve that problem nicely without having the hassle of dealing with [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) (we aren't calculating inter-planetary rocket trajectories here).

FYI, to convert minutes to hours, use this:

```
double hours = min / 60d; // Note the "d"
```

You need the "d" after `60` to make 60 a `double`, otherwise it's an `int` and your result would therefore be an `int` too, making `hours` a whole number double. By making it a `double`, you make Java up-cast min to a double for the calculation, which is what you want.

Comment: Thankyou!! That works!:D Can you also tell me how to convert minutes to hours? I used this: hours = (double)(min)/60..but I guess this is wrong too?

Comment: That works like a charm! And I learnt quite a bit about casting and precision thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

8.16 X 60 comes out to be 489.6 and if you convert this value to int, you will get 489

```
int a = (int)489.6;
      System.out.println("Minutes:=" + a);
```