# convert hours represented in double to duration

Tags: java, duration, java-time

I have a duration stored in the database as a Double, but in my operations on LocalTime I need it to be of type Duration.
I need to be able to change from double to duration and vice versa.

I expect a duration of 3,5 hours to be 3 hours and 30 minutes.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, we can't help without [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the help center and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852).

Comment: What you have done ? post your code.

Comment: I have no idea where to start

Comment: You're out of luck then.

Comment: can you give an idea to get going?

Comment: What technology are you using? JDBC, Hibernate?

Comment: I am using spring-boot

Comment: Related: [Java - Converting hours(in double) to minutes(integer) and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037706/java-converting-hoursin-double-to-minutesinteger-and-vice-versa). I believe there are more similar questions, you will want to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // the Double value
    Double someTime = 3.5;

    // two ways of converting it to Duration
    // (we need to use minutes because Duration.of expects a long, which cannot be fractional
    Duration someDuration = Duration.ofMinutes((long) (someTime * 60));
    Duration someDuration2 = Duration.of((long) (someTime * 60), ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

    // convert the duration back to Double
    Double someTimeAgain = (double)someDuration.toMinutes() / 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your duration is hours as double?
Then you first need to calculate minutes from this. 
This could either be 
long durationInMinutes = durationFromDB * 60 
or, if 0.5 is "half an hour" you need to calculate first the hours and then the minutes and add them... so 3.5h are 180 minutes + 30 minutes = 210 minutes

then you can use java.time.Duration#ofMinutes(long minutes) and get what you need.